# PyInstaller: Single-file executable doesn't run

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a single-file executable for Windows from a Python  application, using `pyinstaller`.

I downloaded the experimental Python 3 branch of `pyinstaller` from [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki) (the file was [python3.zip](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip), but the link is now dead). And I installed it using `python setup.py install`.

Then I created a test python script called `test.py`, with the following content:

```
print('Hello, World!')
```

Afterwards, I ran the following command to create a single-file executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

The command succeeded, and I verified that the file `dist/test.exe` had been generated. However, when I try to run it, all I get is an empty console window. Nothing ever appears, and the program never terminates. It just hangs there forever, until I force close it.

[image: I get an empty console window.]

Calling `pyinstaller test.py` (without the `--onefile` option) works fine. So what *is* the problem?

Notice that using `py2exe` or `cx_freeze` is not an option. It has to be `pyinstaller`.

**UPDATE:** I just tested it under Python 2 (using the normal PyInstaller version), and I ran into the same problem. So, this is not just a Python 3 problem.

Comment: where did you install from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I downloaded it from the link I provided. If you go here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki and scroll down, there is a download link for the Python 3 version.

Comment: the link seems to bring me nowhere? I tried, admittedly using linux  installing using `pip3 install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip`  and it works fine so might be worth giving it a shot unless that is actually the link you were trying to post.

Comment: did you use python or python3 to setup.py install?

Comment: so `python3 setup.py install`?

Comment: No, I used `python setup.py install`. The Python 3 executable (`python.exe`) is in my `PATH`.

Comment: do you only have python3 installed?

Comment: I have both Python 2 and 3. But I have Python 3 on my `PATH`. Typing `python --version` outputs `Python 3.3.5`.

Comment: If that is the case you should file a bug report.

Comment: It worked for me in 64-bit 3.4. Install: `py -3 -m pip install --upgrade https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip`. Build: `py -3 -m PyInstaller.main --onefile test.py`. Test: `dist\test.exe`.

Comment: @eryksun It seems to be a problem with my computer, since it works fine for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.

I found out that the program did, in fact, run. However, it hung for a long time (like 5 minutes!) before displaying the `Hello, World!` message.

The problem was caused by [UPX](https://upx.github.io) (Ultimate Packer for eXectutables), a tool that aims to reduce the size of executable files. PyInstaller uses UPX by default if it finds it on the system. For reasons that I still can't grasp, the UPX-packed executable took an extremely long time to self-extract and run.

Thus, simply running the command with the `--noupx` option fixed the problem.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noupx test.py
```

As a sidenote, adding the `--debug` option to the `pyinstaller` command can usually help identify problems such as this one.

Comment: Interesting - UPX ran quite fast, whenever I used it.